# Why can't I align divs in the following scheme / why is the last container not visible?

Tags: html, css, web, css-position, box-sizing

I would like to align seven divs in another parent container, all should have the same height (as the parent container) and width, except the very first and the last one.

I tried something like that:

**HTML**

```
<div id="weatherBar">
  <div class="arrow"></div>
  <div class="table-wrapper">
    <div>1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-wrapper">
    <div>2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-wrapper">
    <div>3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-wrapper">
    <div>4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-wrapper">
    <div>5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="arrow"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div#weatherBar {
  position: relative;
  width: 60vw;
  max-width: 60vw;
  height: 10vh;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 10vh;
}

div#weatherBar div.table-wrapper {
  min-height: 10vh;
  max-height: 10vh;
  min-width: 10vw;
  max-width: 10vw;
  border: solid 0.5px blue;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div#weatherBar div.arrow {
  min-height: 10vh;
  max-height: 10vh;
  min-width: 5vw;
  max-width: 5vw;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: red;
}
```

But what happens is that the last div does not appear (I attached a picture) and I have no idea why. Could you help me out?

Thank you in advance! :-)

[image: Attached image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `border` of elements are not included by default in the `width` of an element as `box-sizing` is `content-box` by default.

Change it to `border-box` so that borders are *included* in the `width` using:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

See demo below:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div#weatherBar {
  position: relative;
  width: 60vw;
  max-width: 60vw;
  height: 10vh;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 10vh;
}

div#weatherBar div.table-wrapper {
  min-height: 10vh;
  max-height: 10vh;
  min-width: 10vw;
  max-width: 10vw;
  border: solid 0.5px blue;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div#weatherBar div.arrow {
  min-height: 10vh;
  max-height: 10vh;
  min-width: 5vw;
  max-width: 5vw;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="weatherBar">
  <div class="arrow"></div>
  <div class="table-wrapper">
    <div>1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-wrapper">
    <div>2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-wrapper">
    <div>3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-wrapper">
    <div>4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-wrapper">
    <div>5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="arrow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, never heard of that before, but seems to be pretty logical. Will accept your answer asap! ;-)